# jqGrid - Hiding columns in the grid view but showing them in the edit form

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

I am trying to create a grid that will show more details (with possibility for editing) in the form editing mode than in the table view.
Is there a way I can define a column to be hidden in the grid, but shown in the row editing dialog?
(see [here](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:form_editing#editgridrow))

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Sending additional parameters to editurl on JQgrid](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3176157/sending-additional-parameters-to-editurl-on-jqgrid)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You will find the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3176157/sending-additional-parameters-to-editurl-on-jqgrid/3177531#3177531). This other [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3140644/passing-dynamic-params-to-delete-url-method-in-jqgrid/3141029#3141029) can be interesting too.

Comment: Perfect! {hidden: true, editrules: { edithidden: true }} is exactly what I needed

Comment: That's exactly what I needed and was having a hard time finding it!

Comment: @Brian: You are welcome! I think it's a common problem. See [here](http://www.trirand.com/blog/?page_id=393/discussion/form-editing-difference-between-add-and-edit/#p24178) my suggestion about.

Comment: Perfect for me too! {hidden: true, editrules: { edithidden: false }} is exactly what I needed!!! thank you